# input type=range not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

EDIT: I forgot to include the website. Included below.

Could someone look at my site and let me know why they think the range slider isn't showing in IE?

WEBSITE: http://abuv.io/

To clean it up a bit.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 contact-form">
                <form class="form-inline" id="contactform" name="contactform" action="sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

                    <div class="col-sm-8 form-group form-sty">
                        <label for="budget" required>BUDGET</label>
                        <input type="range" id="range" min="500" max="50000" value="500" step="250" />
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
  input[type='range'] {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 25px;
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #94defa 0%, #94defa 2%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 2%);
                border: none;
            }

        input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 25px;
            width: 30px;
        }

        input[type=range]:focus {
            outline: none; 
        }
```

I had added IE Specific CSS to style the slider, and it also had no effect.

This works perfect in all browsers aside from IE, and I'm losing my mind over trying to figure it out. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=range

Comment: Yeah, it shows it's compatible but for some reason it just doesn't show up in IE at all. I even went as far as to create a new input, outside of my form and I just get a blank white box. No styling from my style sheet was being applied at that point. I'm losing my mind over it, never had a problem like this before.

Comment: I also forgot to include the website. I linked it above.

Comment: it work for me. check it http://i79.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0727/4e/67d99ee45b7dad946f4429166693ad4e.jpg

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I probably should have avoided that code snippet. Go to my actual site, and see if you can see the slider: http://abuv.io/

I added that code snippet saying that I had added that CSS and the slider on my actual site still wouldn't show up. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: very sorry. may be check another version jq, jq ui, bs etc...

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, it had to do with the height of the input type=range. Once I increased it to 60px, it showed up in IE. Granted, this isn't what I want it to look like, but it at least gave me something to work towards.

I'm not sure why this happens, but I went through every line of coding, deleting one piece at a time until I came to this conclusion.